# Registering a content provider

Tags: android

I have been trying to create a copy of Android's ContactsProvider. I wanted to make minimal changes to the provider as most of my work will be in another app which will use the data. However, I want to ensure the real contacts are not accessible to the app I am making so I planned to create a copy of the provider. After successfully navigating though the process of creating a copy provider with a different authority, I tried to call my copied provider. At this point I got two errors.

The first one was in my own app where I got the error "Failed to find provider info for 'ContentProvider'" I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7463118/failed-to-find-provider-info-for-contentprovider) answer for that but I had taken care of everything mentioned here already.

The second error happens in my provider: **java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.common.collect.ImmutableSet$Builder** This is probably the reason why I am getting the first error. Because my provider is never able to access the classes that are internal to Android, it is not getting registered as a valid provider and thus my app is not able to "find" the provider.

Here is my Manifest file for the ContactManager:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.prajitdas.contactmanager"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="18"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.prajitdas.contactmanager.ContactManager"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="ContactAdder" android:label="@string/addContactTitle">
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

and the manifest file for the ContactsProvider:-

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.prajitdas.android.providers.contacts"
        android:versionCode="2"
        android:versionName="2.0">

    <permission
            android:name="com.android.voicemail.permission.READ_WRITE_ALL_VOICEMAIL"
            android:label="@string/read_write_all_voicemail_label"
            android:description="@string/read_write_all_voicemail_description"
            android:permissionGroup="android.permission-group.PERSONAL_INFO"
            android:protectionLevel="system|signature"
            />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_DIRECTORY_SEARCH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.UPDATE_APP_OPS_STATS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.voicemail.permission.ADD_VOICEMAIL" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.voicemail.permission.READ_WRITE_ALL_VOICEMAIL" />

    <application android:process="android.process.acore"
        android:label="@string/app_label"
        android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
        android:allowBackup="true">

        <!-- Modified provider authority -->
        <provider android:name="ContactsProvider2"
            android:authorities="fakecontacts;com.prajitdas.android.providers.contacts"
            android:label="@string/provider_label"
            android:multiprocess="false"
            android:exported="true"
            android:readPermission="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"
            android:writePermission="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS">
            <path-permission
                    android:pathPrefix="/search_suggest_query"
                    android:readPermission="android.permission.GLOBAL_SEARCH" />
            <path-permission
                    android:pathPrefix="/search_suggest_shortcut"
                    android:readPermission="android.permission.GLOBAL_SEARCH" />
            <path-permission
                    android:pathPattern="/contacts/.*/photo"
                    android:readPermission="android.permission.GLOBAL_SEARCH" />
            <grant-uri-permission android:pathPattern=".*" />
        </provider>

        <provider android:name="CallLogProvider"
            android:authorities="fakecall_log"
            android:syncable="false" android:multiprocess="false"
            android:exported="true"
            android:readPermission="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG"
            android:writePermission="android.permission.WRITE_CALL_LOG">
        </provider>

        <provider android:name="VoicemailContentProvider"
            android:authorities="com.prajitdas.android.voicemail"
            android:syncable="false" android:multiprocess="false"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="com.android.voicemail.permission.ADD_VOICEMAIL">
        </provider>

        <!-- Handles database upgrades after OTAs, then disables itself -->
        <receiver android:name="ContactsUpgradeReceiver">
            <!-- This broadcast is sent after the core system has finished
                 booting, before the home app is launched or BOOT_COMPLETED
                 is sent. -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PRE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <receiver android:name="PackageIntentReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED" />
                <data android:scheme="package" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
                <data android:scheme="package" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED" />
                <data android:scheme="package" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_CHANGED" />
                <data android:scheme="package" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <receiver android:name="LocaleChangeReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.LOCALE_CHANGED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name="VoicemailCleanupService"/>

        <activity android:name=".debug.ContactsDumpActivity"
                android:label="@string/debug_dump_title"
                android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog"
                >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.prajitdas.android.providers.contacts.DUMP_DATABASE"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <provider android:name=".debug.DumpFileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.prajitdas.android.providers.contacts.dumpfile"
            android:exported="true">
        </provider>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

As you can see, I have basically copied the original manifest files and modified it to the new authorities for my provider. I have done the same for the java code, but it is too big to post here. If anyone can help me identify the steps to either make the android internal calls work or maybe resolve the first problem of "registering" the provider on a phone somehow, it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**com.google.common.collect.ImmutableSet$Builder** isn't actually an internal Android class. It is a part of the Google's [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) library. You need to add Guava's JAR as a dependency to your project to compile it (and, probably, some others dependencies, check the list for the ContactsProvider in its [Android.mk](http://androidxref.com/4.4_r1/xref/packages/providers/ContactsProvider/Android.mk#13)).

The actual way of adding JAR dependency varies depending on what do you use for building your app (e.g. Ant, Maven, Gradle, or Eclipse).